# Set replication factor to 2, in a 3 node Cassandra cluster; but still data is getting replicated to all 3 nodes on insertion

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I have a 3 node cluster, with replication factor of 2 but data is getting replicated on all 3 nodes. This is how I create my keyspace:

> CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':2};

What's missing here ?

Comment: How can you know it's "getting replicated on all 3 nodes"?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra distributes data based on primary key of the row. Any table is generally distributed over all the machines and when you insert a row, it is inserted on "two machines" only (These two machines are not random and can be calculated with `nodetool`)

If you want to know more about how data is distributed by primary key, take a look at partitioners. [Cassandra Partitioners](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Partitioners)

Comment: Your **"any two machines" only** is wrong. Should be **two machines because you set RF=2**

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the difference between those two sentences you highlighted. They mean same (to me atleast)

Comment: Yes, I only meant you don't have "any two machines" per single row, you have "exactly two well-known machines" per row, and the sentence "any two machines" could be misleading (it was to me).

Answer (score 0):

Data is being *distributed* over **3** nodes, and each node holds **2** pieces of data: its own piece of data pertaining to its assigned partitions, and data belonging to its neighbor node.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute `getendpoints` on any of the partition key in a table with in that keyspace. You will get the nodes list which holds that partition. In this case, you should get output as 2 nodes only.

```
$ nodetool getendpoints <keyspace> <table> key
```